# Можно ли вызвать командный файл из другого bat - ника если они в разных каталогах

Tags: cmd, bat

Здравствуйте, сегодня столкнулся с вопросом можно ли вызвать один командный файл из другого, если к примеру вызывающий находится в каком - то каталоге, а файл который он вызывает в подкаталоге вышеупомянутого каталога?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно можно:

```
subdir\file.bat
```

вызов батника из подкаталога subdir текущего каталога

Comment: интересует вызов через call пробовал так: CALL "C:...\...\2.bat" из 1.bat

Comment: ругнулось написало не удаеться найти указанный путь. я так понимаю, что при передаче управления 2.bat и происходит эта ошибка?

Comment: @MuscledBoy нужен call - вызывайте через call как я написал.

Comment: в вызывающем написал: CALL Network\txt_maker.bat - не удается найти путь

Comment: task2.bat - вызывающий, лежит в Admin, каталог Network в - Admin. А txt_maker.bat -n в Network

Comment: понял, прошу прощения. ошибка была в том, что Admin и Network - оба подкаталоги Documents and Settings.  А можно чтобы визывающий командный файл не находился в каталоге, который содержит подкаталог с  файлом, который вызывает? Может вопросы и глупые, но хотель бы знать на будущее, как это делать.

Comment: @MuscledBoy можно

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо